# Is it possible to webscrape video links from Youtube search?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I used Python code in the past to retrieve search result from Youtube.
I tried to use the same code again, however the HTML seems to be an empty skeleton:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def url_to_video(text_to_search):
    query = urllib.parse.quote(text_to_search)
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    response.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    url_list = []
    for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
        url_list.append('https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href'])
    return url_list
```

Did Youtube find a way to block webscraping? Is there a working alternative?

Comment: There is [pytube](https://github.com/nficano/pytube)

Comment: This isn't the same problem.
The question in your link sends a specific url to Youtube, while I send a search query.

Comment: Youtube requires Javascript to display results. BS4 does not run Javascript

Comment: Is selenium the only option?